# Does Visual Studio include some kind of console emulator?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm just starting with Visual Studio 2010, and I'm not even sure if this is the right question to ask. Let me explain what I'm trying to do:

Right now, when developing console applications, I compile/debug, switch to my command prompt, navigate to where the *.exe got dumped and run it--only to find that my output is mising a `\t` or `\n` somewhere--then I need to go back, fix, re-compile, etc., etc.

I'd like to be able to do a compile-on-the-fly-and-run-in-a-window type of thing without having to leave Visual Studio. Maybe a popup launched from VS? Maybe a pane in the interface for the command prompt? Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just hit F5 and it will run... might need to include

```
Console.Readline()
```

so the window does not close too quickly.